# Complexity of Creating a Binary Tree VS Binary Search Tree

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm trying to determine the complexity of creating a binary tree and binary search tree from a list of numbers.

I think that creating a binary tree we have a guaranteed complexity of O(NLogN) since we have to insert N numbers and we can traverse any path of the tree in LogN time to insert a number. This is regardless of the list being sorted or unsorted.

The binary search tree however would have a worst case complexity of O(N^2) since in the worst case the numbers are already sorted (e.g. from smallest to largest), so we will have to make O(N) traversals for each number.

In the average case where the list is not sorted or the numbers are random we would have a complexity of O(NLogN).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What exactly you are asking. Are there any constraints on the structure of the binary tree? Why do  you assume `O(n^2)` for a binary search tree - there are various variants of height-balanced trees with `O(log n)` for inserting a new element (`n` being the currently held number of elements in the tree) ? The original list should not have an effect on the complexity (apart from lower bound of `n`), you sweep it in order processing each entry in turn. Example: Building a degenerate binary tree (`deg v < 3` for all nodes `v`, ie. a linked list) is `O(n)`. ...

Comment: ... Note that with most trees bulk insertions come cheaper when the amortized cost is analyzed instead of `n` isolated updates.